# Nodejs cannot find my node module when calling from cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

When I call my node module from the command line when it is installed globally I get an error saying it

`could not find /node_modules/insect-tool/cli.js`

I check in the global node modules folder and it is there. How do I fix this?

Comment: i think its because you dont have `bin` directory in your module directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its happen because of you doesn't maintain the global module structure or problem with your `pacakge.json` file in `main`   property you have to put `cli.js` instead of index.js

package.json main accept entry point of your module

Place your entry javascript file in `bin` directory

follow this link for more [info](https://bretkikehara.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/nodejs-creating-your-first-global-module/)

> Sample `package.json`

```
{
  "author": "Uzaif nilger",
  "license": "BSD",
  "name": "test-module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "This is my first module.",
  "bin": {
    "test-module-exec": "bin/test-module.js"
  },
  "main" : "cli.js",
  "preferGlobal": "true"
}
```

hope its work for you